# why this javaagent not working with tomcat

Tags: java, javaagents

I am trying to write a javaagent to transform some jdbc driver classes.

```
package org.wxt.xtools.agents;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class JDBCLeakDetector {
    
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws InstantiationException {
        System.out.println("========================== JDBC Leak Detector Agent ==========================");
        MyCT interceptingClassTransformer = new MyCT();
        instrumentation.addTransformer(interceptingClassTransformer);
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.wxt.xtools.agents;

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class MyCT implements ClassFileTransformer{

    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        System.out.println(classBeingRedefined.getName());
        for(Class<?> i : classBeingRedefined.getInterfaces()) {
            if(i.getName().equals("java.sql.Driver")) {
                System.out.println("Driver implementation found: " + classBeingRedefined.getName());
            }
        }
        return classfileBuffer;
    }
    
}
```

The goal is to redefine any `java.sql.Driver` implementation classes and add some logic before it's `connect` method, when attatch my agent jar to a tomcat, the `ClassFileTransformer#transform` never get called. I expect many outputs by

```
System.out.println(classBeingRedefined.getName());
```

but there is none, and I can confirm my agent is loaded with

```
System.out.println("========================== JDBC Leak Detector Agent ==========================");
```

What's wrong with my code? pleas help

Comment: How is the agent registered?

Comment: @LMC `export JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:jdbc-leak-detector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -server -Xms512m -Xmx${MEM_SIZE}g -Xss256k -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9089 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -DCmdbType=tbm"`

Comment: From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html#transform%28java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.String,java.lang.Class,java.security.ProtectionDomain,byte%5B%5D%29): "**classBeingRedefined** - if this is triggered by a redefine or retransform, the class being redefined or retransformed; if this is a class load, null." --- You don't redefine classes (triggered by calling `Instrumentation.retransformClasses​`), so `classBeingRedefined.getName()` will throw a NPE. Exceptions in transformers are silently ignored.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn thanks bro, I switched to bytebuddy, but what you said is correct, after adding transformer  `instrumentation.retransformClasses(Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"));` did the trick

Comment: The correct fix would be to not use `classBeingRedefined` and instead extract the info from the passed bytecode (using something like ASM).